# Determinant of solution of linear equation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a direct way or method to know if the solution to a linear ODE is invertible? I mean, let $A(t)$ be a ($n$ times $n$) matrix and denote by $X(t)$ an unknown Matrix (of the same dimensions) which satisfies
$$X'(t) = A(t) X(t), \quad X(0)=X_0\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.$$

Assume there is a unique solution $X(t)$. Is there a way to know if $X$ is invertible, i.e.
$$\det X(t) >0 \quad \mbox{ for every } \quad  t\geq 0$$
Thanks!

Comment: Hint: [Liouville's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A(t)$ is communicated, then the solution is $$X(t)=e^{\int_0^t A(t)dt}X_0$$ and $$\det X(t)=e^{\int_0^t tr(A(t))dt}\det X_0$$.

In general case, i.e. $A(t)$ may not be communicated. Then note that
$$\det X^*(t)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\det X(t)=(\det X(t))^{n-1}\cdot tr(X'(t)X^*(t))$$
$$\det X^*(t)=(\det X(t))^{n-1}$$
$$X(t)X^*(t)=\det X(t)I$$
so $$\frac{d}{dt}\det X(t)=tr(A(t)X(t)X^*(t))=tr(A(t))\det X(t)$$.

Comment: Yes, but this is not always possible is it? What conditions are you assuming on $A$ to be able to solve the Equation explicitly like that? I think $A(t)$ and $A(s)$ need to commute for every $s,t$. This is too restrictive :(

Comment: Yes! Liouville's formula of course! Thank you ;)

Comment: @AlfredChern It's true that the solutions of $X' = A(t) X$, is $X(t) = \exp \left(\int_{0}^{t} A(s) ds\right) X_0$?. I think that is only true when $A(t)= A_0$